# "Reader base" en español

Tags: traducción, modismos

¿Cuál es la manera más correcta de traducir "reader base"? Lo que quiero decir es que un escritor "develops a reader base", que obviamente no se refiere a desarrollar los propios lectores.

Lo más cerca que encontré es en [Linguee](http://www.linguee.com/english-spanish/search?source=auto&query=reader%20base), que ofrece sólo dos traducciones que realmente se refieren a esto:

> *Our newspaper counts with a loyal reader base* = Nuestro semanario cuenta con fieles lectores

Esta me parece la más natural, pero ¿cómo puedo "desarrollar" un adjunto de lectores?

> *The reader base in the mainland is obviously demographically higher* =
>   La base de lectores residentes en los Estados Unidos es obviamente demográficamente mayor.

Este tipo de frase es lo que busco, pero la he visto sólo una vez por todo el Internet, puede ser que es una traducción demasiado inglesa/literal. ¿Os suena bien?

Supongo que habría otras frases semejantes que se refieren a un "base" de gente y pueden adaptarse, pero no se me ocurrió ninguna.

Comment: Gracias por los Edits.

Comment: Buena pregunta, y bien planteada. ¡Bienvenida a Spanish Language!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si buscas en el diccionario de la RAE la palabra **[base](http://dle.rae.es/?id=5ASmP2Z)**, te encuentras con la siguiente acepción:

> 2. f. Conjunto de personas representadas por un mandatario, delegado o portavoz suyo. U. t. en pl. con el mismo significado que en sing.

Esta acepción se usa mucho en los partidos políticos, con frases como

> La cúpula del partido decidió consultar a las bases si apoyaba o no a la oposición.

El quid de la acepción es que el conjunto de personas está representado por alguien. En este caso, más que un representante lo que hay es un nexo de unión, la persona que une al grupo no es un representante político sino un escritor al que todos leen. Si nos quedamos con la parte de la acepción de "grupo de personas", no cuesta trabajo pensar en una "base de lectores", término que no me suena para nada raro, y que he leído en más de una ocasión.

Comment: Con respecto a cómo traducir *develop*  yo diría *hacerse con*: A writer develops a reader base = Un escritor se hace con una base de lectores.

Comment: @Yay cierto, se me olvidó ese detalle, ¡gracias por el apunte!